# Fixed Header icon overlap

Tags: html, css

[image: The output]

I have the following screen, i have a progress bar, its icons are being overlapped and its disturbing the navigation bar.

progress bar css :

```
ol.progtrckr li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}
ol.progtrckr li:before {
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -2.5em;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Navigation Bar css:

```
#navwrapper {
margin:0 auto;
background-color: #3A87AD;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a `z-index` to your navigation bar.

```
#navwrapper {
    z-index: 100;
    ....
}
```

Elements with a larger `z-index` overlap others.

For more information have a look at [**z-index - MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).